# Water for shielding during space travel

Tags: water, shielding

Use less water for shielding during space travel by transferring water to the side of the craft exposed to the solar radiation source?

Comment: *[make it so!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h74oZ.jpg)*

Comment: The answers to this question might explain things: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-materials-provide-the-best-protection-from-cosmic-radiation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @user29784 it is hard to guess what you are really asking here. It sounds like a good idea, but can you expand on this and ask something that can have a clear, objective answer? Thanks!